# Get an float from a string Blackberry OS

Tags: java, blackberry

I am trying to change my screen depending of the device version in BB.

I got this instruction:

```
String deviceOS = DeviceInfo.getPlatformVersion();
```

But it gives me a string like this: 4.0.1.3 and I want to get just the first 2 numbers in a float variable. It is developed in java.

The first number almost sure will never be higher than 9 but the second, maybe it reachs to 10 or two digits.

I know this is a simple question for java developers but I haven't use java in a couple of years and I don't remember the basics.

Comment: One of my blackberrys displays 9.X.X.... and my app works. I also think the latest is OS7 but it displays higher.

Comment: Which phone?  Are you sure it is not just a bug.  Check in Options --> About to see what software level the BB thinks is installed.

Comment: It is a BB9360 and says: v7.1.0.714 Platform 9.6.0.111 So I think I am returning platform version and not OS version.

Comment: Is DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion() what you need then?

Comment: Yes, getSoftwareVersion shows SO version. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse this yourself.  The easiest way is to just use deviceOS.indexOf(".") and then strip off the digits (and the ".").  There are always 4 levels (i.e. 3 "." chars), so you don't have to worry about end conditions.  Look at the API documentation for String and StringUtilities for other helpful methods.

[API Documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/)

Comment: I parse it by myself and I did it. I just had to read a little bit to remember java. Thanks for api reference.